# How can I make Word Quick Parts work after each deployment from Visual Studio?

Tags: list, document-library, word, quick-parts

I have set up a SharePoint 2013 document library with content types and Word document templates, all declared (XML) and deployed from Visual Studio. In the Word document I have Quick Parts, which work whenever I insert them after a fresh deployment.

The problem is; if I make some changes to my project and re-deploy, the links between the document library fields and the Quick Parts in the document are lost. Same template, same fields, but they no longer work. I suspect this is due to the fact that the GUID of the document library is changed upon a new deployment. I have tried setting the ID parameter of the List tag in the schema.xml, and also that of the ListInstance for the document library, but SharePoint just ignores this.

Is there a way to make this work so that whenever I deploy the Quick Parts will work without re-inserting them?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not using Visual Studio, but when working with QuickParts and copying / moving documents between document libraries, the SourceID property on the field must be the same for the quick parts to persist. Try setting this property to something fixes - like the name of your project.

[Field schema reference at msdn.microsoft.com](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa979575.aspx)